# Simple HTML + PHP form not submitting correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, html, forms

Hey so I need to make a contact us form for a website I'm working on and I'm having some trouble actually with using the right syntax to correctly send the form data over to an email account.

The problem right now is that when I click the submit button, nothing happens. No email is sent and absolutely nothing happens on the HTML page itself.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
            <form style="margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;" id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span5">
                        <label>Full Name *</label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="John Smith">
                        <label>Email Address *</label>
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" required="required" class="input-block-level" placeholder="(123) 456-7890">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span7">
                        <label>Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="input-block-level" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="center">
                    <input value="submit" type="submit" name="submit" required="required" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

--

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $from = "mail@company.com";
    $to = "company@company.com";
    $subject = "Contact Us Submission - Company";
    $body = "Here is the contact form submission information:\n\nName:\n $name\n\n E-Mail:\n $email\n\n Phone:\n $phone\n\n Message:\n $message";

    $userto = "$email";
    $usersubject = "Thank you, from Company.";
    $userbody = "Dear $name,\n\nWe have received your response from the Company Contact Us form and will be in touch shortly. If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to ask us.\nYou can simply reply to this email at mail@company.com\n\nSincerely,\nCompany";
}

if ((mail($to, $subject, $body) && mail($userto, $usersubject, $userbody))
{
    echo "<p>Thank you. Your response was received. You can now close this tab.</p>";
}
else
{
    echo "<p>Sorry, there was an error sending your response. Please try again. If the problem persits, please contact Company via another method.</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error (in which case, what error)? Is it sending to an incorrect address? Please explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form itself is fine, though personally I'd remove the target='_blank' attribute however there is a syntax error in the php.

Change the above lines to:

```
if ( mail($to, $subject, $body) && mail($userto, $usersubject, $userbody) ) {
    echo "<p>Thank you. Your response was received. You can now close this tab.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Sorry, there was an error sending your response. Please try again. If the problem persits, please contact Company via another method.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried to fix the parentheses error that I had but still, nothing happens upon clicking submit. And you're right, I don't really need target="_blank" so I removed that as well.

Comment: Does the form submit at all? You have posted MOST of the form, I assume you do have a full form with closing tag?

Comment: No it doesn't submit. Click submit after entering values into all of the text boxes doesn't do any changes. I uploaded the rest of the code. It was was comment formatting I messed up.

Comment: Ok - Open the console and watch for errors on page load because the form itself is fine and processing at the back end also seemed fine once the issues with the mismatched braces was corrected ~ leading me to believe that the mail would be sent. Thus I think the error must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Ok - had a look. The error about jQuery is not affecting anything and when I copied the html, stripped out all the css / javascript and ran it as a test it submitted fine.

Comment: When I submit the form on the live site, the form does submit because I get a response in the console `<p>Sorry, there was an error sending your response. Please try again. If the problem persits, please
 contact Dhirana 2016 via another method.</p>` ~ the jQuery function is not serialising the form data ~ it is an empty submission.

Comment: Hi @RamRaider: But, without headers, is it possible to send mail ? Just asking AAJ TAK.

Comment: @NanaPartykar - do you mean is it possible to send an email, using `mail`, as the @OP did above with no additional headers? Yes.

Comment: Yeah Yeah @RamRaider. You are right. Is it possible ?

Comment: yes, there are three mandatory arguments to `mail`, namely recipient, subject and message.

Comment: Ok Ok. Till now i was not knowing. Thanks @RamRaider. Blessings From INDIA.

Comment: @RamRaider Thank you so much for your help. Since I didn't create this contact form (it came in a template), I didn't know exactly how this data was being parsed into the email. I just commented out all of the javascript related to the contact us form and just let the PHP handle all of the form details. This worked flawlessly.